# Passing a Jar arguments from Javascript in Ubuntu

Tags: javascript, java, jar, arguments

I've got a Javascript snippet I am using successfully to pass arguments to a jar file for calculations on my windows machine but when I uploaded it to my server its telling me it cannot access the jar file.  I can run the jar file from terminal on my Ubuntu server so I am not entire sure why it's not working from the JavaScript file.

```js
 const cmdArgs = [...vendFat, priceFat, amountFat];
 /* variable 'command line code' */
 const cmdCode = `java -jar ./Java2/createOrder.jar ${cmdArgs}`;
  var exec = require('child_process').exec, child;
 child = exec(cmdCode,
   function (error, stdout, stderr){
     console.log('Response: ' + JSON.stringify(stdout));
   res.send(stdout);
     //console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
     if(error !== null){
       console.log('exec error: ' + error);
     }
 });
```

And here is the terminal response:

exec error: Error: Command failed: java -jar ./Java2/createOrder.jar s,e,l,l,0,100
Error: Unable to access jarfile ./Java2/createOrder.jar

Comment: post the full stacktrace

Comment: Everything that is in the terminal from running the JS program is as follows:    
`listening on port 8082
Response: ""
exec error: Error: Command failed: java -jar ./Java2/createOrder.jar s,e,l,l,0,100
Error: Unable to access jarfile ./Java2/createOrder.jar`

Comment: There's probably an error with the permissions of the file, you should set them